# Why didn't Kenobi tell Anakin that he had snuck aboard Padme's ship?

Tags: star-wars

I think that Anakin had some dark thoughts circulating in his head when he saw Kenobi aboard Padme's ship. If Kenobi had just told Anakin that Padme had nothing to do with him being on her ship, then I feel like things would have turned out differently.

Comment: That wasn't his point of view.

Comment: Because only a Sith deals in absolute.